# MIP: Do binary variables perform better that integers?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, binary-variable

I have a model where investments can be done in blocks. Now I could model this with integer or binary variables. Does anybody know which one is the better choice in terms of computational performance?

Comment: This is very similar to the [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/does-exchanging-integer-variables-by-binary-variables-strengthen-a-mip) asked by another user minutes ago. Also related to [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/how-to-choose-between-high-number-of-binary-variables-or-fewer-number-of-integer).