# Using binary variable or integer variable in Constraint Programming (CP)?

Tags: constraint-programming, binary-variable, or-tools, cp-sat, integer-variable

I am trying to solve an assignment problem by Constraint Programming (CP). Let us consider a task assignment problem that have $|M|$ tasks and $|N|$ machines, each task has different processing time required on each machine, and each machine has a maximum capacity (number of tasks can be processed). The objective is to assign each task to a single machine with respect to the precedence requirements, such that the overall processing time can be minimized.

To model the assignment decisions, we can use $|M||N|$ binary variables (represent whether a task is assigned to a machine) or $|M|$ integer variables (each has a domain of $[1, |N|]$, represent the machine that each task is assigned to). I am little experienced with CP, but I have read material that says less variable, and more constraints can be beneficial for solving CP. So, I suspect that using integer variables is better.

My questions are:

**- How the choice of variable type (binary / integer) impacts the algorithm efficiency?**

**- Will CP solvers (e.g. OR-Tools) convert integer variables into binary ones automatically, such that there is no difference between binary variables and integer variables?**

This question is related to [How to choose between high number of binary variables or fewer number of integer (not only 0 and 1) variables in a IP formulation?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3209/8718) and [Does exchanging integer variables by binary variables strengthen a MIP?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6555/8718), which are in the context of Mathematical Programming, rather than CP.

Comment: As far as I know, and at least for the scheduling problems, the main benefit of the $CP$ is by using the `interval` and `sequence` variables in contrast to the $MIP$ formulation. I am not sure if by defining the binary or integer variables directly, the performance may have a considerable difference.

Comment: Imho it depends a bit on your Solver-API and your modelling-approach. In most cases i would expect n*m optional interval-variables and all APIs i know will need boolean-vars to enable/disable those intervals. On the other hand, there is nothing more efficient to express the "select a single machine" than an int-var (and a sum=1 on bools can be rather inefficient). Usually this means you will have both, bool and int and channel/link those to get the best of both worlds. See [Gecode API](https://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelIntChannel.html). This applies to more classic CP

Comment: Some solvers might deviate a lot from classic CP and things might change significantly. ILOG CP probably has high-lvl constraints and or-tools cp-sat is based on lazy-clause generation. In both cases, it's more important to identify a fitting modelling-approach (cp-sat examples: flex-jss + gate-sched) before focusing on the assignment subproblem. Both solvers know about scheduling-structures and i would highly recommend those. or-tools will indeed use booleans internally eventually, even for int-vars, but not for the reasons you expect. It's a necessity for LCG conflict-analysis (explanations)

Comment: CP-SAT is a very good ILP solver. So even with purely linear model, it is worth using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the CP-SAT solver, the rule of thumb is the following:

- if you need to check if a variable ==/!= value, then you should use an array of Boolean variables instead
- the start, end, size of interval variables must be integer variables
- index of element constraint, variables in a constraint like all_different, table, automaton: they will all be expanded to Boolean variables as the constraints will also be expanded to Boolean and enforced linear constraints.

So for quantities, sums, time: use IntVar
For assignment: use BoolVars.